# Qt signal not working when passing pointer to a struct

Tags: c++, qt

I have a Qt form that emits a signal; the signal passes a pointer to a structure which contains a load of data that the main window then sends out of my qextserialport.

This was working, but I have done something [unknown] and now when I connect the signal to a slot, unless I change it so that the singal does not pass anything, the connection to the signal will not work.

In mainwindow.cpp I have this:

```
void MainWindow::qt1245ValuesReceivedFromKeypad(char *dataPtr)
{

    bool connected;

    qt1245Window = new qt1245(this);
    connected = connect(qt1245Window,SIGNAL(sendMessageToKeypad(struct qt1245MessageStruct *qm)),this,SLOT(sendToQT1245(struct qt1245MessageStruct *qm)));
    qt1245Window->setupDataFromKeypad(dataPtr);
    qt1245Window->keyMapping(BinData);
    qt1245Window->keyDropDownChanged("DIM");       
 //   connected = connect(qt1245Window,SIGNAL(sendMessageToKeypad()),this,SLOT(sendToQT1245()));
    qt1245Window->exec();        
}
```

If I uncomment the second connect, and comment the first, and change the appropriate code, the connect works.

The structure is defined thus:

```
struct qt1245MessageStruct
{

    quint8 *dataPtr;
    quint8 length;
    quint8 keypadStartAddress;
    quint8 programType;

};
```

In qt1245.h I have this as part of the class declaration:

```
signals:
    void sendMessageToKeypad(struct qt1245MessageStruct *qm);
```

in qt1245.cpp. the signal is emitted as follows:

```
void qt1245::sendQT1245Message(qt1245MessageStruct *qm)
{

    emit sendMessageToKeypad(qm);

}
```

Can anyone shed any light on why connect returns false if I try to pass the pointer to the structure please? Also, is there away of making Qt give information as to why the connect fails, rather than just saying it *has*?

If you need any more information, I will post it. I'm not sure at this juncture what would assist.

FWIW I'm on Linux, Qt Creator 4.9.0 based on Qt 5.12.2.

Comment: provide a [mre]

Comment: If you are using Qt 5+, *please* stop using the old `SIGNAL` and `SLOT` macros that both result in slow code and only give you (non fatal) errors at run-time. Instead use the modern pointer-to-member-function, compile time checked syntax.

Comment: "This was working, but I have done something [unknown]" - Then check out a previous commit from your version control software and see where the error was introduced. If you are not using version control or not committing often enough to bisect errors, then *I* have no empathy left..

Comment: The name of the parameter does not go into the SIGNAL SLOT macros.

Comment: @JesperJuhl I *am* using Mercurial. As far as the old macro is concerned, I wasn't even aware there was a new one, I am but an occasional user of Qt, just for little programs for production.

Comment: @Thomas Thank you so much, it was that simple. If you make that an answer I'll upvote and accept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The parameters in the connect call are wrong.

```
connect(qt1245Window,
        SIGNAL(sendMessageToKeypad(struct qt1245MessageStruct*qm)),
        this,
        SLOT(sendToQT1245(struct qt1245MessageStruct *qm)));
```

The name of the parameter does not go into the `SIGNAL`and `SLOT` macros. The correct syntax is:

```
connect(qt1245Window,
        SIGNAL(sendMessageToKeypad(struct qt1245MessageStruct*)),
        this,
        SLOT(sendToQT1245(struct qt1245MessageStruct *)));
```